# Pulling from GitHub to IIS

Tags: iis, git, telnet, github

To update my website I need to pull from GitHub to IIS, remotely, not by using RDP.

How can I do that? TelNet does not support git and I don't like installing OpenSSH ( it needs CygWin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behold! 30 characters are required.

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [PowerShell remote session](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

Or use [Sysinternal psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) to run command on remote system.